# Why are relative bindings in a virtualized data grid sometimes not resolved?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am *occasionally* getting binding errors from an element in a cell of a data grid.  The problematic binding has a relative source.  The appearance of the error seems to be dependent on the number columns and on virtualization.

I've recreated a similar problem in a simplfied project. (It's a bit contrived, but it demonstrates the problem.)

Here is the window when it first opens:
[image: Here is the window when it first opens]

Here is the window when it is resized (note the blank cells):
[image: Here is the window when it is resized. Note the blank cells.]

Here is the xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.DataGridVirtualizationBindingTest"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:test="clr-namespace:Test"
        Title="DataGridVirtualizationBindingTest" Height="300" Width="300">

    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="IsReadyTemplate">
            <TextBox 
                Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.IsReady, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type test:DataGridVirtualizationBindingTest}}}"
                />
        </DataTemplate>

    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Records}"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True"
            VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True"
            VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
            EnableRowVirtualization="True"
            EnableColumnVirtualization="True"
            >

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Ready" CellTemplate="{StaticResource IsReadyTemplate}"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Ready" CellTemplate="{StaticResource IsReadyTemplate}"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Ready" CellTemplate="{StaticResource IsReadyTemplate}"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Ready" CellTemplate="{StaticResource IsReadyTemplate}"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Ready" CellTemplate="{StaticResource IsReadyTemplate}"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Ready" CellTemplate="{StaticResource IsReadyTemplate}"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Ready" CellTemplate="{StaticResource IsReadyTemplate}"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Ready" CellTemplate="{StaticResource IsReadyTemplate}"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Ready" CellTemplate="{StaticResource IsReadyTemplate}"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Ready" CellTemplate="{StaticResource IsReadyTemplate}"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Ready" CellTemplate="{StaticResource IsReadyTemplate}"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Ready" CellTemplate="{StaticResource IsReadyTemplate}"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Ready" CellTemplate="{StaticResource IsReadyTemplate}"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Ready" CellTemplate="{StaticResource IsReadyTemplate}"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Ready" CellTemplate="{StaticResource IsReadyTemplate}"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Ready" CellTemplate="{StaticResource IsReadyTemplate}"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Ready" CellTemplate="{StaticResource IsReadyTemplate}"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Ready" CellTemplate="{StaticResource IsReadyTemplate}"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Ready" CellTemplate="{StaticResource IsReadyTemplate}"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Ready" CellTemplate="{StaticResource IsReadyTemplate}"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Ready" CellTemplate="{StaticResource IsReadyTemplate}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The window's data context is an instance of this class:

```
class DataGridVirtualizationBindingTestVm 
{
    public DataGridVirtualizationBindingTestVm()
    {
        Records = new ObservableCollection<Record>(Enumerable.Range(1, 4000).Select(i => new Record { Field1 = i.ToString() }));

        IsReady = true;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Record> Records { get; private set; }

    public bool IsReady { get; set; }
}

public class Record 
{
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
}
```

The error is

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='Test.DataGridVirtualizationBindingTest', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.IsReady; DataItem=null; target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

It doesn't occur for every cell. The framework is 4.5.2.

Why is the binding sometimes not resolved?

Comment: I suppose `DataGridVirtualizationBindingTestVm` vs `DataGridVirtualizationBindingTest` is just a typo?

Comment: @grek40 They are two different classes.  One is the view model, the other the view.

Comment: @Sinatr This is not a duplicate because in my case the binding is on an element in the visual tree (TextBox), not on the DataGridTemplateColumn which is not.

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove

```
EnableColumnVirtualization="True"
```

Normally you don't need that (only if you have dozens of columns shown at once, but this is not something good for user experience - having long horizontal scroll) and it seems to be the case of the problem.

Comment: That does indeed solve the simplified problem.  Unfortunately it does not solve the problem in the full application I'm working on. (I can't post that code, and it would be much too verbose even if I could).  I am searching for insight into _why_ the problem occurs, in hope that it would lead me to a solution.

Comment: Did you remove that in main project (do not forget to rebuild all) or you can't (then explain reasons)? And it still has issues (then you are doomed to create [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) without `EnableColumnVirtualization`)? Reasons of the problem as per your example is something related to virtualization process, you can try to use someone's else *working* experience (e.g. [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34405/WPF-Data-Virtualization)) instead.

Comment: I removed both `EnableColumnVirtualization` and `EnableRowVirtualization` from the main project _and_ rebuilt yet still have the problem.  I think my simplified project _is_ an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as I see no reason why column virtualization should not be supported.  Why would DataGrid have the property EnableColumnVirtualization if it is not to be used.  In the end, I will probably work around the problem by using the ElementName property instead of a relative source.  Thanks for the effort all the same.

Answer (score 1):

This is no definite answer, but the issue with virtualization could be, that WPF is creating some cell elements in advance, that are not yet attached to the visual tree. At least the output of `PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=Low` suggests this scenario.

Normal output (note, your `DataGridVirtualizationBindingTest` is `MainWindow` in my case):

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=60380718): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=60380718): Found data context element: <null> (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 73 :     Lookup ancestor of type MainWindow:  queried ContentPresenter (hash=26040159)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 73 :     Lookup ancestor of type MainWindow:  queried ContentPresenter (hash=23961813)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 73 :     Lookup ancestor of type MainWindow:  queried Border (hash=14171850)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 73 :     Lookup ancestor of type MainWindow:  queried DataGridCell (hash=30197729)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 73 :     Lookup ancestor of type MainWindow:  queried DataGridCellsPanel (hash=54907338)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 73 :     Lookup ancestor of type MainWindow:  queried ItemsPresenter (hash=18305611)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 73 :     Lookup ancestor of type MainWindow:  queried DataGridCellsPresenter (hash=31492160)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 73 :     Lookup ancestor of type MainWindow:  queried SelectiveScrollingGrid (hash=6218983)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 73 :     Lookup ancestor of type MainWindow:  queried Border (hash=28775807)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 73 :     Lookup ancestor of type MainWindow:  queried DataGridRow (hash=45107596)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 73 :     Lookup ancestor of type MainWindow:  queried DataGridRowsPresenter (hash=13951517)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 73 :     Lookup ancestor of type MainWindow:  queried ItemsPresenter (hash=46444112)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 73 :     Lookup ancestor of type MainWindow:  queried ScrollContentPresenter (hash=40710552)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 73 :     Lookup ancestor of type MainWindow:  queried Grid (hash=29895441)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 73 :     Lookup ancestor of type MainWindow:  queried ScrollViewer (hash=32389509)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 73 :     Lookup ancestor of type MainWindow:  queried Border (hash=57561173)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 73 :     Lookup ancestor of type MainWindow:  queried DataGrid (hash=23331898)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 73 :     Lookup ancestor of type MainWindow:  queried Grid (hash=49388651)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 73 :     Lookup ancestor of type MainWindow:  queried ContentPresenter (hash=15440763)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 73 :     Lookup ancestor of type MainWindow:  queried AdornerDecorator (hash=34437342)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 73 :     Lookup ancestor of type MainWindow:  queried Border (hash=66222128)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 73 :     Lookup ancestor of type MainWindow:  queried MainWindow (hash=34299654)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 72 :   RelativeSource.FindAncestor found MainWindow (hash=34299654)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 78 : BindingExpression (hash=60380718): Activate with root item MainWindow (hash=34299654)
```

While for some cells, the binding is repeatedly evaluated until last chance is reached:

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=60974811): Resolving source  (last chance)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=60974811): Found data context element: <null> (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 73 :     Lookup ancestor of type MainWindow:  queried ContentPresenter (hash=39741069)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 73 :     Lookup ancestor of type MainWindow:  queried ContentPresenter (hash=61133431)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 73 :     Lookup ancestor of type MainWindow:  queried Border (hash=47344455)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 73 :     Lookup ancestor of type MainWindow:  queried DataGridCell (hash=47247550)
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='WpfApplication2.MainWindow', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.IsReady; DataItem=null; target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

Since the cell element is not yet part of the visual tree, ancestor relation bending fails.

A workaround would be to give a name to some element in the hierarchy (eg. the DataGrid) and bind to the `ElementName` with your path `DataContext.IsReady`

**Alternative**

An alternative solution would be to 'hack' the information into your viewmodel. In your example, since you utilize the `IsReady` information in all of your data items, you can extract an interface with relevant information and store it into the record, then bind the view to the interface object.

```
public interface IStatusContainer
{
    bool IsReady { get; set; }
}
public class DataGridVirtualizationBindingTestVm : IStatusContainer

{
    public DataGridVirtualizationBindingTestVm()
    {
        Records = new ObservableCollection<Record>(Enumerable.Range(1, 4000).Select(i => new Record { Field1 = i.ToString(), Container = this }));
     // ...
}

public class Record
{
    public IStatusContainer Container { get; set; }
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
}

<DataTemplate x:Key="IsReadyTemplate">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Container.IsReady}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

I would recommend this approach if the container information is reasonably related to the individual items or if static cross-references in WPF are not an option for some reason.

Comment: I noticed the same pattern in the binding trace and came to a similar conclusion.  I also arrived at same workaround using ElementName.  Great minds.  I am loathe to call bug, but this smells like one.

Comment: Good find! Do you know if there is some suitable event/callback where you could enforce an update of the broken `RelativeSource` bindings? The suggested workaround works, but is required for all templates down the chain. A bit hard to maintain.

Comment: @l33t sorry, I hardly remember anything about this 5 year old answer :) Anyway I would advise you to pick some way to avoid broken bindings in the first place instead of hoping to repair them later. If the presented workarounds are not suitable in your case, it might be better to ask a question with a [mcve] that distinguishes your case from the ones that are covered here

Comment: Ok. FWIW, the error seems to be linked with the `Recycling` setting of the `VirtualizingStackPanel`. Somehow it decides to use a broken container.